# Rails: User can't accept friend request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making my first solo rails project. It's a facebook clone, and at the moment I can't get a user to accept a friend request. Please let me know if the information posted isn't sufficient enough to help work towards an answer.

```
friend_request_controller.rb

class FriendRequestsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_friend_request, except: [:index, :create]

def index
    @incoming = FriendRequest.where(friend: current_user)
    @outgoing = current_user.friend_requests
end

def create
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    friend = User.find(params[:id])
    @friend_request = current_user.friend_requests.new(friend_id: friend)

    if @friend_request.save
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    end
end

def update
    friend = User.find(params[:id])
    @friend_request = current_user.friend_requests.find(friend_id: friend)
    @friend_request.accept
end
```

---

```
show.html.erb

Hello my my email is <%= @user.email %>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   <li>
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>

   <li><%= link_to 'All Users', users_path %>     
</li>
<% else %>
<li>
<%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>  
</li>
<% end %>
<ul>

<% current_user.friend_requests.each do |request| %>
<h4>You have new friend requests from:</h4>
<li>
  <%= User.find(request.friend_id).email %>
  <%= link_to "Accept",  friend_request_path(friend_id: @friend),method:"put"   %>  
  <%= link_to "Decline", "#" %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

---

I know something is wrong with my link_to helper here

```
user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :friend_requests, dependent: :destroy
has_many :pending_friends, through: :friend_requests, source: :friend
has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 end
```

---

```
friend_request.rb

class FriendRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'

def accept
  user.friends << friend
  destroy
end

def destroy
end

end
```

Comment: You provided a lot of code, which is great! But all you've provided in terms of problem content is "I know something is wrong with my link_to helper here", which isn't very helpful. What's happening, what should happen? Is that route even defined? Your link looks fine...

Comment: well at the moment when I click on the accept link, I get this error:         PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "id" LINE 1: ...uests" WHERE "friend_requests"."user_id" = $1 AND "id"."frie... ^ : SELECT "friend_requests".* FROM "friend_requests" WHERE "friend_requests"."user_id" = $1 AND "id"."friend_id" = 3 LIMIT $2

Comment: Have you tried my answer below?

Comment: Yes it was able to push me a bit further. As of now I'm trying to have an inverse relationship created once the friend request is accepted. Quick question about your response. How did you know to do request.friend_id when there is only some called friend_request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<%= link_to "Accept",  friend_request_path(friend_id: @friend),method:"put"   %>
```

Try to change `@friend` to `request.friend_id`:

```
<%= link_to "Accept",  friend_request_path(friend_id: request.friend_id),method:"put"   %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do what @araratan has mentioned + in your frined_request controller, replace params[:id] with params[:friend_id].

Comment: Thank you. I caught that second part and made a change